Nuxt 3 app deployed to Azure. Environment variables are ignored in nitro section of nuxt.config.ts
I've found that my Nuxt 3 app deployed to Azure is ignoring environment variables in nuxt.config.ts.
This is what I have in local:
nitro: {
    storage: {
      redis: {
        driver: 'redis',
        port: REDIS_PORT,
        host: REDIS_HOST,
        username: '',
        password: REDIS_PASS,
        db: 0
      }
    }
  },

But if I want it to work on the production machine, I have to remove the 3 environment variables and hardcode them. Which is totally inconvenient, as I have a modified nuxt.config.ts file that I can never push. And when switching branches, I have to copy that section, discard the file, switch to the new branch, and paste the section.
I saw an example in the docs, but I wonder if the environment variables being ignored is a known issue or if I'm missing something really obvious.
Thanks in advance to anyone who might help :)

Can you provide the github repo if possible ?

What does your  azure app service log stream show ?

Is this azure specific? Does it work if you run yarn build && yarn preview in local? My hunch is that those env variables are available in your local globally, not exclusive to the repo

Have added your environment variables in .env  file of your project,

I created a sample nuxt application which prints environment variables as output.

In your projects root directory, create a .env file and add

REDIS_PORT=<port>
REDIS_HOST=<Hostname>
REDIS_PASS=<password>


I've refered this doc and  addeddotenv to nuxt.config.ts  , it will load environment variables from .env

import  'dotenv/config'
require('dotenv').config()


I've used process.env to access environment variables within the nuxt.config.ts file.
This make sure that environment variables are retrieved from the .env instead of being hardcoded.

Complete nuxt.config.ts:
import { defineNuxtConfig } from  'nuxt/config'
import  'dotenv/config'
require('dotenv').config()
export  default  defineNuxtConfig({
nitro: {
storage: {
redis: {
driver:  'redis',
port:  process.env.REDIS_PORT,
host:  process.env.REDIS_HOST,
username:  '',
password:  process.env.REDIS_PASS,
db:  0
}
}
},
runtimeConfig: {
public: {
redisPort:  process.env.REDIS_PORT,
redisHost:  process.env.REDIS_HOST,
redisPass:  process.env.REDIS_PASS,
}
}
})

pages/index.vue:
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Environment Variables</h1>
    <ul>
      <li>REDIS_PORT: {{ redisPort }}</li>
      <li>REDIS_HOST: {{ redisHost }}</li>
      <li>REDIS_PASS: {{ redisPass }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
<script setup>
import { useRuntimeConfig } from '#imports'
const config = useRuntimeConfig()
const redisPort = config.public.redisPort
const redisHost = config.public.redisHost
const redisPass = config.public.redisPass
</script>

Here, the environment variables are displayed by the Vue component by using  useRuntimeConfig.
This way Nuxt3 application uses and loads environment variables both in development and production.
Output after deployment:


@lmc3s3f0r Is your issue resolved?

This worked. Thank you very much!

@lmc3s3f0r I'm glad it worked!
